# Is it possible for my Mercurial hook to call code from another file?

Tags: python, mercurial, python-import, mercurial-hook

I have a hook function named `precommit_bad_branch` which imports `hook_utils`. When invoking `precommit_bad_branch` via a commit I get the following error message:

```
error: precommit.branch_check hook raised an exception: No module named hook_utils
abort: No module named hook_utils!
```

It looks like I'm not allowed to call `hook_utils` from `precommit_bad_branch`. The code works fine if I call it explicitly without involving Mercurial.

Is it possible for my hook to call code from another file?

My hgrc hook part looks like this:

```
[hooks]
precommit.branch_check = python:C:\workspaces\hg_hooks\next_hooks.py:precommit_bad_branch
precommit.debug_code_check = python:C:\workspaces\hg_hooks\common_hooks.py:precommit_contains_debug_code
preupdate.merge_check = python:C:\workspaces\hg_hooks\next_hooks.py:preupdate_bad_merge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `C:\workspaces\hg_hooks` directory in your `PYTHONPATH` and you will be able to write

```
[hooks]
precommit.branch_check = python:next_hooks.precommit_bad_branch
```

in your configuration file and you will also be able to do

```
import hook_utils
```

inside any Python file, including the `next_hooks.py` file.

Alternatively, you can modify `sys.path` from `next_hooks.py`, perhaps with code like this:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

import hook_utils
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I thought it was some security thing on Mercurials behalf. :-)

Comment: Nope, it's normal Python import mechanics :)